sageworksheet indexing issues
I'm trying to use a sage worksheet for a much different problem, but the issue I'm having can be expressed concisely as follows:
Let's say I have some list A. I want to make several lists (call them MDN(j)) where each list has entries '0,' the 4th to jth elements of A, '99'.
In the end, when I ask it to print MDN(j), it just prints '0,' the 4th to max(j)th elements of A, '99.' That is, if I have j in [4,..,9] and ask it to print MDN(6), it will print MDN(9).
Why can't I access indexed MDN's? Is there a better way to do this?
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
print('A=',A)

M=[0]
print('M=',M)

N=[99]
print('N=',N)

for j in [4,..,9]:
    D=[A[i] for i in [1,2,..,j]]
    print('D=',D)
    MDN(j)=M+D+N
    print('M+D+N=',MDN(j))

#why is this printing MDN(9)?
print(MDN(6))

output:


See also https://ask.sagemath.org/question/79295/sage-worksheet-indexing-issues/

What sort of object is MDN supposed to be? The assignment MDN(j) = ... is not a standard Python construction, and in Sage, it defines some sort of symbolic function. If you print(MDN), the output will be
j |--> (0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 99)

That is, it takes as input the symbolic variable j (which is also created when you do the assignment MDN(j) = ...) and assigns it to the output (0, 2, ..., 99).
You could instead define MDN to be a Python dictionary:
MDN = {} # new line

for j in [4,..,9]:
    D=[A[i] for i in [1,2,..,j]]
    print('D=',D)
    MDN[j]=M+D+N  # change parentheses to brackets
    print('M+D+N=',MDN[j])   # same change

Then print(MDN[6]) will yield
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 99]

Indeed, print(MDN) will yield
{4: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 99],
 5: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 99],
 6: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 99],
 7: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 99],
 8: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 99],
 9: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 99]}


I will give it a try right now. Thank you. I am just going to try and copy and paste what you wrote, though I don't see any changes beyond changing the () to []. I don't know what a python dictionary is. If the copy and paste doesn't work, I will look that up next. Thank you.

There is also the line marked “new line” (the first one in my first block of code).

Thank you thank you thank you! I would have sworn I tried switching to brackets before. ha! Very thankful for the help!
